# IE8 won't place image over a div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a simple CSS and HTML website, trying stuff out.

I wanted to make an image float over a div. Something like so:

```
    <div id="big_container">
        <img id="img1" src="images/fun.png"/>
        <div id="some_container"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS for it:

```
#big_container{ width: 960px; height: 270px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 42px;}

#some_container{ width: 100%; height: 198px; border: 1px solid #cccccc;}

#img1{ width: 69px; height: 200px; float: left; position: relative; left: 200px;}
```

What this does, is instead of placing the `img` over the `some_container` div, it places it FIRST and after the image, underneath it, it places the `some_container` div.

How can i get the image to float over the div? Firefox and Chrome display it correctly. IE8 does not.

**EDIT**

I tried removing `relative` and `left`, according to Kyle Sevenoaks. But it still displays it above the div, and does not overlap.

Comment: I think you should go and learn about floats and positioning. You only need _one_. Not both.

Comment: Well, i wanted to put the image above the div, and then position it a little bit to the left. Anyway, if i remove the position attribute, it still does not display it correctly.

Comment: This is because you'd have `float: left;` still in effect. Do you have a diagram of what you want to acheive?

Comment: try adding `z-index:9999;` in you `#img1` css

Comment: @kakarott: z-index inherits from the parent, this would be useless.

Comment: So, i removed `relative` and `left` from the CSS code. It still displays it incorrectly.

Comment: What do you mean by incorrectly?

Comment: It displays the image and the div like so: http://www.wovel.com/product_photos/Vertical_Sequence_lg.jpg instead of placing the image OVER the div, in front of it, whatever you wanna call it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use position: absolute; to make it display over the div you require:

```
#img1{ width: 69px; height: 200px; position: absolute; left: 200px;}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/dLnm7/

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that with this you should add `position: relative;` to the parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/dLnm7/1/

Comment: hmm. That works. But it positions it in relation to the <html>  tag, and not its first parent which is `big_container`. When i resize the window, the image moves :(

Comment: Hm, then you can add position: relative; to the container. But this is the effect you are after, yes?

Comment: O.O That worked. Now, explain to me, if you will ... why it worked with relative to the parent container and why it didn't without it...

Answer (score 1):

Floating an element will not place it over the top of other elements within the same parent. You've also tried to use a "left" CSS value on a relatively positioned element. "float" works on relatively positioned elements, "left" works on absolute and fixed positioned elements.

Here is your CSS to position "img1" over the top of "some_container" (includes short hand for margin declarations). Note "position:relative;" applied to the parent "big_container".

```
#big_container{ width: 960px; height: 270px; margin: 42px auto 0; position:relative;}
#some_container{ width: 100%; height: 198px; border: 1px solid #CCC;}
#img1{ width: 69px; height: 200px; position: absolute; left: 200px; top:0px; }
```

You will now see that IE8 wasn't at fault here. Other browsers may have been kind to you and ignored any conflicting CSS declarations to give you the desired result. IE8, being less sophisticated, probably wasn't compensating and taking your CSS literally.

Comment: An absolutely positioned element begins its positioning at 0px top and 0px left of the first div container which is relatively positioned. In your case, this was <html> or <body> or perhaps your first div container on the page. It's useful to apply position:relative; to a parent whenever you apply position:absolute; to a div - just for sanity reasons ;) Some browsers will assume the parent is relative, others won't.